# Bash and jq - Find a key contained in a variable and change it's value

Tags: json, bash, jq

Let's say I have the following json.

```
{
    "userid":334,

    "Parameters": [ 
        {
            "ParameterValue": "james", "ParameterKey": "name" 
        },
        {
            "ParameterValue": "22", "ParameterKey": "age" 
        },
        {
            "ParameterValue": "belfast", "ParameterKey": "city" 
        },
        {
            "ParameterValue": "software", "ParameterKey": "career" 
        }
    ]
}
```

I have some code which takes the JSON and extracts all of the keys and their values.

```
echo $my_json | jq -r '.Parameters[] | .ParameterKey + "=" + .ParameterValue' >> $OUTPUT_FILE
```

If I look in my output file I have something similar to this:

```
name=james
age=22
city=belfast
career=software
```

How can I find, say "career" and change it's value before it is placed in the $OUTPUT_FILE? Example below:

```
name=james
age=22
city=belfast
career=consultation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jq** solution:

```
echo $my_json | jq -r --arg career "consultation" '.Parameters[] 
     | [.ParameterKey, if (.ParameterKey == "career") then $career else .ParameterValue end] 
     | join("=")' > outputfile
```

- `--arg career "consultation"` - passing value `"consultation"` into *jq* script as a predefined variable named `$career`
- `join("=")` - join/implode *key* and *value* using `=` as separator

---

The `outputfile` contents:

```
name=james
age=22
city=belfast
career=consultation
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I would change this to ammend a '#' to the start of the line if the ParameterValue is empty?

Comment: @Xenidious, what does mean *to ammend a '#' to the start of the line*? Show how it should look in that particular case

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `map()` function:

```
jq -r '.Parameters | map(
           if .ParameterKey == "career" then (.ParameterValue = "foo") else . end)
       [] |  .ParameterKey + "=" + .ParameterValue'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which uses a generalization of [from_entries](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries)
to convert the data to an intermediate object, [object multiplication with *](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Multiplication,division,modulo:*,/,and%) to update the desired keys and a function to format the output taking into account blank values.

First we assume jq will be invoked with the [--argjson](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) parameter as follows to specify the key to be replaced:

```
$ jq -Mr --argjson replace '{"career":"consultation"}' -f filter.jq data.json
```

where `data.json` contains the sample data and `filter.jq` contains the following filter:

```
def from_entries(k;v): map({(k):v})|add;
def format_output:     keys[] as $k | if .[$k]!="" then "\($k)=\(.[$k])" else "#\($k)=" end;

  .Parameters
| from_entries(.ParameterKey;.ParameterValue)
| . * $replace
| format_output
```

Sample output:

```
age=22
career=consultation
city=belfast
name=james
```

If instead we run it as

```
$ jq -Mr --argjson replace '{"career":""}' -f filter.jq data.json
```

The output is

```
age=22
#career=
city=belfast
name=james
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##nZKxboMwEIZ3nuJ6ZYAKGJJOoDxBl05dCIrccLQEMNQ2iRDw6qUOqA1IDFU83f336/N/lk9fQ2uAPlhLEmmM/nb77EzKKxOsIEVCog8hjOL1tH/V0vbG8pq0FU@6l@jMRi/UXAdcd3gD9c7/mZvNGpB93Mt7pzxhUq1Bj6lq7qTKMlEXJmgVq3USc/BYRUZvdINm/xp8xB6YBFNQlbMjGR0YRkwJJKIsDsSVSElaWXC2fShYZbVWZvvn3u5YHAeTsRQFU4eyVlWt/PGujBoZRiM2gw7SBLzQzKKHHSKoT@KAe8vM7N3eGnUbgXJJgI@TrFuu4Tqwd/sVOtgikjffOPCWr2NrtwdP860WMYfhu6xUWnI5uC6v89xN@VV2XcEu7uT5AQ)